# C# Windows Service Invalid credentials

Tags: c#, defaultnetworkcredentials

I have a C# windows service used to pull some files from another machine on the same domain.
When I run my windows service as a console application, it pull files from the other computer. However, running it as a windows service return :
Invalid credentials for: 192.168.100.53  (ServerNotFoundMIPException)

I tried to change the service Log On as Local Service or Network Service but no success.
The following is the OnStart method:
    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)

In application properties, Security section, I checked Enable ClickOnce security settings, This is a full trust application.

The Credential type I used is:

```
case CredentialType.Windows:
{
var nc = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

What I am missing so my windows failed to pull files from the other computer ?

Comment: If I used my machine (uri = "http://localhost), it works as a windows serivce, changing it to my machne IP address (uri = "http://192.168.100.73), it failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are reading files from a Windows share, like `\\COMPUTER2\Share\Path\file.ext`.

Account under which the server runs must be able to

1. Access the network,
2. Authenticate with the domain controller
3. Able to logon to COMPUTER2 from the network (assigned via Control Panel->Admin tools->Local Security Policy).
4. Have access rights to the share in question.

LocalSystem and LocalService fail at #1. No network access.

NetworkService gives you #1, but fails on #2 - it's a local account and domain controller does not know about it.

What you need is to run the service under a specific **domain** acount, not local account, and configure that account to be able to logon remotely to COMPUTER2 and have read access to share Share.

Alternatively, you may expose your files via different protocol that does not require authentication, e.g. ftp or http.

Comment: I am using a third party api to pull specific files, there is no share folder.

Comment: Then it depends on how that third party API handles authentication. If it uses Windows authentication, chances are, you still need to run the service under a domain account. Network security is different from (orthogonal to) .NET Code Access Security. The fact that your local CLR considers your code "full trust" does not mean much to Windows or to the 3rd party API.

Comment: I added OurDomain\MyUsername to log on AS, and it started successfully, so in services I can see it MyUsername@OurDomain.com